# Copy a sheet from a SpreadSheet file to a Google Drive folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I learn how to use Google Script. I'm trying to make a copy of a sheet form a spreadsheet into a Google Drive folder. That was possible manualy but i need to do that with Google Script.

I try :

```
var desFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
DriveApp.getFileById(spreadSheet.getId()).makeCopy("desired file name", destFolder);
```

But it copy all the spreadSheet, i need to copy one sheet not the entire SpreadSheet.
How can i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script 1:

```js
function sample1() {
  var sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name you want to copy.
  var folderID = "###"; // Please set the folder ID.

  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  var srcSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(srcSpreadSheet.getId()).makeCopy("desired file name", destFolder);
  var dstSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(file);
  dstSpreadsheet.getSheets().forEach(s => {
    if (s.getSheetName() != sheetName) {
      dstSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(s);
    }
  });
}
```

- In this modification, the Spreadsheet is copied to the destination folder. And, the sheets except for a sheet you want to use are deleted.

#### Modified script 2:

```js
function sample1() {
  var sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name you want to copy.
  var folderID = "###"; // Please set the folder ID.

  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  var srcSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var srcSheet = srcSpreadSheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var dstSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("desired file name");
  var dstSheet = srcSheet.copyTo(dstSpreadsheet);
  dstSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(dstSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0]);
  dstSheet.setName(sheetName);
  DriveApp.getFileById(dstSpreadsheet.getId()).moveTo(destFolder);
}
```

- In this modification, a new Spreadsheet is created and it is moved to the destination folder. And, copy the sheet you want to use to the created Spreadsheet. And, the default sheet is deleted.
- I noticed that when I saw the 2nd sample script and, when the value of `sheetName` is the same as the default sheet name, an error occurs. So, I modified it.

#### References:

- [deleteSheet(sheet)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#deleteSheet(Sheet))
- [copyTo(spreadsheet)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copytospreadsheet)

Comment: Ok, i realise that was not possible to copy directly a sheet. Thank for the two method, it's verry helpfull !

Comment: @Cotwo Tobias Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 1):

you'll need to create an empty spreadsheet and copy specific sheet using your [`copyTo` method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copyTo(Spreadsheet)).

Something like:

```
var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("desired file name")
var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName("specific_sheet_name")
sheet.copyTo(newSpreadsheet)
```

Answer (score 0):

here's my solution after so many attempts

```js
  

   
  function copySheet()
 {
    const sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    
 // the sheet i want to copy
    const productSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("products");
    
    // creating a new spreadsheet to copy the sheet to, and giving it a name
    const newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("invoice_products");
    
    // Get the ID of the destination folder (can be copied from the URL)
    const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(xxx);
    
   // move the new spreadsheet to the wanted folder
    DriveApp.getFileById(newSpreadsheet.getId()).moveTo(destinationFolder);
    
    // Copy the "products" sheet to the new spreadsheet
    const copiedSheet = productSheet.copyTo(newSpreadsheet);
    copiedSheet.setName("x_products");
    
    // optional: delete the default first sheet in the new spreadsheet
    newSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(newSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0]);
    
}
```